# How do I set a title to a jframe?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am a beginner and I designed a frame but I didn't do it manually. Instead I used the design tool in Netbeans. I am trying to set a title with the following code in my main method but I still wont get it.

```
    ...  
 /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new QueuesFrame().setVisible(true);
            QueuesFrame.SetTitle("myCase senario");
        });
    }
```

Comment: I’d imagine the design tool has a title property for JFrames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is case sensitive, so `SetTitle` should be `setTitle` and you need to perform the operation on an instance of the frame

```
QueuesFrame frame = new QueuesFrame();
frame.setTitle("myCase senario");
//frame.pack();
//frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true)
```

> Instead I used the design tool in Netbeans

If you interested in become a decent developer, I would strongly recommend avoiding the form editors until you have a better grasp of how the Swing (or even JavaFX) APIs actually work - it will give you a better baseline of skills and reduce the mess that form editors get you into

Comment: Why a wiki post?

Comment: @notyou Because 1- The question should be closed as a duplicate, but I'm to lazy; 2- It could be answered better by the OP making the effort to read the JavaDocs, any good tutorial and search on Google or SO; 3- The question/answer adds little value to SO.  So why answer it at all? 1- Because we've all been that developer whose just trying to get something to work without the experience to know how to fix it (thank you SO); 2- To stop other "rep-vampires" from jumping on a "simple question" band-wagon.  I hope someone just closes it as duplicate

Comment: @MadProgrammer It's an exact duplicate only if you know that `QueuesFrame` is a `JFrame`.

Comment: @corsiKa As I stated, I’m to lazy to go hunting for it